# How to make an area black, outside of a cgrect on a UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, core-graphics

I am using OpenCV to detect face in an image, however my question is not related to opencv, i think its related to the CoreGraphics only. 
Here is my code in a UIImageView (category) for detecting face and drawing a rectangle over it.

```
- (void)detectFeature:(NSString *)feature
{

NSUInteger                scale;

IplImage                * image;
IplImage                * smallImage;
NSString                * xmlPath;
CvHaarClassifierCascade * cascade;
CvMemStorage            * storage;
CvSeq                   * faces;
UIAlertView             * alert;
CGImageRef                imageRef;
CGColorSpaceRef           colorSpaceRef;
CGContextRef              context;
CvRect                    rect;
CGRect                    faceRect;


scale = 2;

cvSetErrMode( CV_ErrModeParent );

xmlPath    = [ [ NSBundle mainBundle ] pathForResource: feature ofType: @"xml" ];
if (xmlPath == nil) {
    NSLog(@"we don't have an xml file for this feature. this feature is can not be detacted");
}
else {
    [self scaleAndRotateImage:self.image];
    image      = [ self createIplImage: self.image ];
    smallImage = cvCreateImage( cvSize( image->width / scale, image->height / scale ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );

    cvPyrDown( image, smallImage, CV_GAUSSIAN_5x5 );

    cascade = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade * )cvLoad( [ xmlPath cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding ], NULL, NULL, NULL );
    storage = cvCreateMemStorage( 0 );
    faces   = cvHaarDetectObjects( smallImage, cascade, storage, ( float )1.2, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize( 20, 20 ) );

    cvReleaseImage( &smallImage );

    imageRef      = self.image.CGImage;
    colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    context       = CGBitmapContextCreate
    (
     NULL,
     self.image.size.width,
     self.image.size.height,
     8,
     self.image.size.width * 4,
     colorSpaceRef,
     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault
     );

    CGContextDrawImage
    (
     context,
     CGRectMake( 0, 0, self.image.size.width, self.image.size.height ),
     imageRef
     );

    CGContextSetLineWidth( context, 1 );
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor( context, ( CGFloat )0, ( CGFloat )0, ( CGFloat )0, ( CGFloat )0.5 );
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor( context, ( CGFloat )1, ( CGFloat )1, ( CGFloat )1, ( CGFloat )0.5 );

    if( faces->total == 0 )
    {
        alert = [ [ UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle: @"No Feature" message: @"No features were detected in the picture. Please try with another one." delegate: NULL cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil ];

        [ alert show ];
    }
    else
    {

        for( int i = 0; i < faces->total; i++ )
        {
            rect     = *( CvRect * )cvGetSeqElem( faces, i );
            faceRect = CGContextConvertRectToDeviceSpace( context, CGRectMake( rect.x * scale, rect.y * scale, rect.width * scale, rect.height * scale ) );

            CGContextFillRect( context, faceRect );
            CGContextStrokeRect( context, faceRect );
        }

        self.image = [ UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGBitmapContextCreateImage( context ) ];
    }

    CGContextRelease( context );
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpaceRef );
    cvReleaseMemStorage( &storage );
    cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &cascade );
    cvReleaseImage( &smallImage );
}

}
```

What this code does is, it draws a rectangle over my UIImage. and leave the rest of the image as it is. I would like to change all the area of UIImage to black except the detected rectangle.

As of right now, i have managed to crop the image. But i don't want to do that. the size of the image should be same, i just want to black out the rest of the area of the image.

Comment: I don't have code available right now, but I know you can perform mask operations with OpenCV that should accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have broken my ans in steps.Hope it helps.

After detecting all faces, draw the filled rect, instead of path as new image. There after draw a black image, of original images size.

Thenceforth create a new context , draw black image, then drew the path image(image with rect path) with kCGBlendModeDestinationOut blend mode.Save the result as result1.

Again create a new context , draw original image, then draw the path image(image with rect path) with kCGBlendModeDestinationIn blend mode.Save the result as result2.

Take a new context draw both images result1 and result2 kCGBlendModeNormal.
Hope it helps.
Happy Coding.. !!

Comment: I do get your point. just having hard time translating into actual code.

Comment: If you provide me sample image i.e. original one and image with path you got. I can provide sample code.

Comment: In my code, i am already using Rect to draw onto the context like this - CGContextFillRect( context, faceRect ). i am not using any path of sort.

Comment: "What this code does is, it draws a rectangle over my UIImage" i am asking this image.